# How to consolidate messages to display them in one thread in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

*Google Translation from original post:*

Since I moved to Outlook 2007, every time I write an answer, the answer comes in a separate email.

Does anyone know how to change the settings so that the original message and the answer (or all answers) will be consolidated to one message that displays all the thread, without saving the previous message?

Comment: this is an english forum , and so it'd be a good idea to translate to English.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. One of the conditions of posting here is that you post in English. If you have trouble with English then posting the Google translation along with the original Hebrew is OK. Someone will be able to correct any translation errors for you.

Comment: Google translate gives it as "Since I moved to, every time when I wrote to get an answer, the answer comes from a separate email.
Does anyone know how to change the settings so that the original message and the answer or answers will be consolidated to one that displays all the thread, without saving the previous message?"    I think he wants a threaded view like Gmail

Comment: @barlop Thanks, I took the liberty of pasting that in. Hope you don't mind. omri, as ChrisF has already said, please check if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

These couple of links might help, with explanations on how to make Outlook 2007 show conversations:
 - http://www.davidgrant.ca/make_outlook_behave_gmail
 - http://mo.notono.us/2009/09/mimicking-outlook-2010s-conversation.html